# Using Python & Regex, find duplicate lines

Tags: python, regex

I'm stuck at a part on a project and I need to eliminate duplicate lines in a file that is 162 million lines long. I have already implemented the following script (but it didn't get rid of all duplicate lines):

```
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
outfile = open('C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Documents\\Python\\Pagelinks\\pagelinkSample_10K_cleaned11.txt', "w")
for line in open('C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Documents\\Python\\Pagelinks\\pagelinkSample_10K_cleaned10.txt', "r"):
    if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
        outfile.write(line)
        lines_seen.add(line)
outfile.close()
```

I need to write a regex expression that will eliminate any duplicated lines! Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I'm inserting the 162 million lines into MS SQL 2014. When using bulk insert, it informs me there are duplicate entries as an error message.

Maybe it's not working because my method stores the "seen" lines in memory and then keeps scanning , and eventually runs out of memory because the file is so large?

Comment: Are you sure the lines you think are duplicates are actually duplicates?

Comment: This code looks pretty correct. Look at the [recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) for `unique_everseen`.

Comment: Do they need to be in the same order as the original file?

Comment: See [Memory efficient way to remove duplicate lines in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467353/memory-efficient-way-to-remove-duplicate-lines-in-a-text-file-using-c)

Comment: Why do you think you need a regex? In any case, provide a reasonable error description if you want help, see also the posting guidelines. As it stands, your question is off-topic.

Comment: One way to possibly reduce memory usage is to store the hash of the line instead of the line itself.

Comment: actually `set` (atleast in python) already use `hash` to optimize their impact on memory. (according to my tests just now using `unique.__sizeof__()` and `sum(i.__sizeof__() for i in unique)`)

Comment: Hey all, Thanks for the quick responses!

I'm entering the data into a database, and when i bulk insert, it displays a message saying there are duplicate entries. The file is 162 million lines like i said above, so scrolling through the entire thing is impossible. Not really sure what to do !

Comment: the database tells you there are duplicates but doesn't give you an option to remove them for you? That's silly.

Comment: Correct. It doesn't give me the option to remove them. I'm using MS SQL Server 2014 LocalDb version

Comment: Do you have to bulk insert?

Comment: Have you tried adding `line = line.strip()` as the first thing the loop?

Comment: Well, I suggest to hash each line and store in set. This could be cpu intensive task but definitely memory efficient and will indeed remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You likely don't need Python if you have a file with 162M lines.

You seem to run on Windows. If you had Linux / OSX / *BSD, or installed Cygwin, you could just do:

```
cat the_huge_file | sort --unique > file_without_duplicates
```

On Windows, there's a `sort` shell utility, so

```
sort <the_huge_file >sorted_file
```

should work, hopefully in a memory-efficient way. Maybe it also has a switch to remove duplicates; consult `sort /?`

If it does not, removing duplicate lines after sorting is a piece of cake: read the file line by line (not the whole file at once), only use a line if it's different from a previous line. A trivial Python program could do it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, it's for a school project and the prof is requiring we use python scripts to "clean" the data

Comment: If lines are even 40 chars long, 167M lines are 6.6 GB; likely more that your available RAM. So you need to do like big boys who wrote the `sort` utility do: read some amount of lines, so that it fits into memory, sort them and remove duplicates, write to a temporary file. Read more lines, create another temporary file, etc until all source lines are over. Then start merging these files (creating other temporary files as you go if needed), also removing dupes. A merge needs 2 lines worth of RAM and decreases the number of files; once you've merged two last files, you're done. See "merge sort".

Answer (score 0):

Here is memory efficient solution using python and sqlite. This script will read line by line from text file and insert into sqlite with unique index. If it detects a duplicate, it will print line# and content of line duplicating.

In the end, you'll have cleaned data in sqlite database. You can easily export data from sqlite into cvs or even directly into SqlServer.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
with conn:
    file_name = 'C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Documents\\Python\\Pagelinks\\pagelinkSample_10K_cleaned10.txt'

    sql_create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(line TEXT UNIQUE)"
    sql_insert = "INSERT INTO data VALUES (?)"

    conn.execute(sql_create)
    conn.commit()

    index = 1

    with open(file_name, "r") as fp:
        for line in fp:
            p = line.strip()
            try:
                conn.execute(sql_insert, (p,))
            except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
                print('D: ' + str(index) + ':  ' + p)
            finally:
                index += 1
        conn.commit()
```